# use string variable as query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

i am using codeigniter and i need to use aggregate function in query. so i have this query.

```
"SELECT Dated, CASE WHEN `Account_ID` = 2 then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as 'Nadeem', 
CASE WHEN Account_ID = 2 then SUM(Kaat_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as 'NadeemKaat', 
CASE WHEN `Account_ID` = 7 then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as 'Abid', 
CASE WHEN Account_ID = 7 then SUM(Kaat_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as 'AbidKaat', 
CASE WHEN `Account_ID` = 8 then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as 'Sajid', 
CASE WHEN Account_ID = 8 then SUM(Kaat_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as 'SajidKaat' 
FROM `tblstockdetail` GROUP BY `Dated`"
```

i have generated this query through a simple foreach loop

```
$stock = $this->Kharkaar_Model->get_stockdetail();

        $sql = '"SELECT Dated, ';

        $numItems = count($stock);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($stock as $key => $value) 
        {

            if(++$i === $numItems)
            {
                $sql.= "CASE WHEN `Account_ID` = ".$value['Account_ID']." then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as '".$value['AccountName']."', <br /> 
            CASE WHEN Account_ID = ".$value['Account_ID']." then SUM(Kaat_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as '".$value['AccountName']."Kaat' <br /> FROM `tblstockdetail` GROUP BY `Dated`";
            }
            else
            {
                $sql.= "CASE WHEN `Account_ID` = ".$value['Account_ID']." then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as '".$value['AccountName']."', <br /> 
            CASE WHEN Account_ID = ".$value['Account_ID']." then SUM(Kaat_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as '".$value['AccountName']."Kaat', <br /> ";

            }

        }

        $sql.= '"';
```

now when i try to get result of this query

```
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

it is giving me a syntax error, otherwise when i put this query direct into

```
$result = $this->db->query(// string query here );
```

it is running fine.

Comment: What syntax error do you get, php or MySQL?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT Dated, CASE WHEN `Account_ID` = 2 then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as '' at line 1

Comment: You have an extra `"` in front of your `select`.

Comment: print the $sql before execution and see what query you get run that query manually to check errors

Comment: my query is 100% fine..the issue is when i save this query in variable and pass that variable to query function then it gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `foreach` should be like this

```
$stock = $this->Kharkaar_Model->get_stockdetail();

$sql = "SELECT Dated, ";

$numItems = count($stock);
$i = 0;
foreach ($stock as $key => $value) 
{

    if(++$i === $numItems)
    {
        $Account_ID = $value['Account_ID'];
        $AccountName = $value['AccountName'];

        $sql.= "CASE WHEN `Account_ID` =  $Account_ID then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as $AccountName, 
        CASE WHEN Account_ID = $Account_ID then SUM(Kaat_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as $AccountName 
        FROM `tblstockdetail` GROUP BY `Dated`";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql.= "CASE WHEN `Account_ID` = $Account_ID then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as $AccountName,
        CASE WHEN Account_ID = $Account_ID then SUM(Kaat_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as $AccountName";

    }

}
```

**if `TRUE`**

```
"SELECT Dated, 
CASE WHEN `Account_ID` =  $Account_ID then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as $AccountName, 
CASE WHEN Account_ID = $Account_ID then SUM(Kaat_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as $AccountName 
FROM `tblstockdetail` GROUP BY `Dated`"
```

**if `FALSE`**

```
"SELECT Dated, 
CASE WHEN `Account_ID` = $Account_ID then SUM(Total_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as $AccountName,
ASE WHEN Account_ID = $Account_ID then SUM(Kaat_Bricks) ELSE 0 end as $AccountName"
```

---

**Wrong in your code**

1. Wrapping too much with `'` and `"`
2. `<br />` don't use irrelevant tags

---

**Suggestion**

1. Use Variable (`$Account_ID`) instead of actual array pointer (`$value['Account_ID'];`) - ***It's EASY to UNDERSTAND and easy to DEBUG***

Comment: thank you for your time.i think the issue was with <br /> tags i just removed those and query is working great :) thank you